# Passing Array from JavaScript to Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is code for javascript which calls asp.net CustomHeatMapDate

```
$('.Date').change(function () {
    var data = [];
    console.log();
    var dateList = [{"Date":"03/23/2016"}, {"Date":"03/24/2016"}];
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
       url: "/Home/CustomHeatMapDate",
       data: { Date: dateList },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                pushdata(data[i]);
            }
        }
    })
```

Here is the Asp.net Controller

```
public IActionResult CustomHeatMapDate(Array[] Date)
{           
    return View();
}
```

But Date Array is null

Comment: Try to use `traditional:true` property.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues, I'll go through them and explain why and how to fix them.

The first one is the data you are sending to the controller, you've structured it so the outcome will be `{Date:[{"Date":"03/23/2016"}, {"Date":"03/24/2016"}]}` when it should look *like* this `{Date:["03/23/2016", "03/24/2016"]}` then you will be sending a flat array up instead of an array of objects.

The second issue is your datatype in your controller, you've got it set to `Array[]` This is expecting and array of arrays. What you should have is `DateTime[]`, this will now expect an array of date(times). This will mean you'll have to change your dates being sent up to `2016-03-23` so it can be deserialized properly.

The last is the fact that you're doing this as a `GET` which doesn't really handle passing structured data in the parameters as it puts it all in the query string, which as your array of dates gets longer you may run the risk of it becoming too long. I'd recommend using a `POST` instead, although if you really do want to do a `GET` then as Alexandru-Ionut Mihai said add `traditional:true` to the ajax properties

**TL;DR** The data structure on the client and server side are wrong

Putting it all together your code should look something like this

**JS**

```
$('.Date').change(function () {
    console.log();
    var dateList = ["2016-03-23", "2016-03-24"];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/CustomHeatMapDate",
        data: {
            Date: dateList
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                pushdata(data[i]);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

**C#**

```
public ActionResult CustomHeatMapDate(DateTime[] Date)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

P.S there is no need to specify `async:true` as by default JQuery Ajax will set it to true.